# Cannot change column entries from grades (strings) into numeric values (GPA)

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a CSV file where I have 'Grade' column with entries (grades) from 'F' and 'D+' up to 'A' (not 'A+' though). So, what I want to do is to convert these values from, for example, 'A' into 4.0 (numeric value), 'A-' into 3.7 (again - numeric).

So far, I tried **revalue()** from *plyr* library, but it did not work.

```
     filtered_data$Grade <- 
        as.numeric(as.character(revalue(filtered_data$Grade, 
        +                                   c("A"="4.0", "A-"="3.7",
        +                                     "B+" = "3.3", "B" = "3.0",
        +                                     "B-" = "2.7", "C+" = "2.3",
        +                                     "C" = "2.0", "C-" = "1.7",
        +                                     "D+" = "1.3", "D" = "1.0",
        +                                     "F" = "0.0"))))
        Error in revalue(filtered_data$Grade, c(A = "4.0", `A-` = "3.7", 
        `B+` = "3.3",  : 
        x is not a factor or a character vector.
```

I also tried doing some tricks with **as.numeric(as.character(foo))**, but this did not work as well.

Third, 'hardcoding' method, did not work as well because I tried to implement *for loop* to change every entry in a column, but I got this message

```
    Warning message:
    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(11L, 16L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 16L,  :
     invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could define a data frame with the values as a lookup table and then merge it to your original data, thus creating a new variable with the numeric values. E.g. `lookupTable <- data.frame(Grade = c("A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "F"), Grade_num = c(4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0, 0))`. And then `filtered_data <- merge(x = filtered_data, y = lookupTable, by = "Grade")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your Grade column to a factor will do the trick with your first method:

```
filtered_data<-data.frame(Grade=c("A","B+", "C", "A-","D","B", "B-","C+","C-","D+","F"))
filtered_data$Grade <- as.factor(filtered_data$Grade)

filtered_data$Grade <- revalue(filtered_data$Grade, 
   c("A"="4.0", "A-"="3.7",
     "B+" = "3.3", "B" = "3.0",
     "B-" = "2.7", "C+" = "2.3",
     "C" = "2.0", "C-" = "1.7",
     "D+" = "1.3", "D" = "1.0",
     "F" = "0.0"))
```

Comment: The second line is not needed since the first line returned the Grade column as a factor variable. I don't think you correctly identified the source of the error. If there were a dataframe that were read in with the typical `read.*` functions then any character valued column would be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where your error occurred but I think there is a much simpler method of using a lookup vector than asking for a new package and function:

```
> trans.vec=  c("A"="4.0", "A-"="3.7",
+    "B+" = "3.3", "B" = "3.0",
+    "B-" = "2.7", "C+" = "2.3",
+    "C" = "2.0", "C-" = "1.7",
+    "D+" = "1.3", "D" = "1.0",
+    "F" = "0.0")
```

That created a named vector. Then you can just push the values of the Grade column through the extraction function applied to that vector:

```
> filtered_data$num.char <- trans.vec[filtered_data$Grade]
> filtered_data
   Grade num.char
1      A      4.0
2     B+      2.7
3      C      2.3
4     A-      3.7
5      D      1.3
6      B      3.3
7     B-      3.0
8     C+      1.7
9     C-      2.0
10    D+      1.0
11     F      0.0
> str(filtered_data)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Grade   : Factor w/ 11 levels "A","A-","B","B-",..: 1 5 6 2 9 3 4 8 7 10 ...
 $ num.char: chr  "4.0" "2.7" "2.3" "3.7" ...
```

The values of the vector do not need to be character. You could skp all the as.character.as.numeric folderol by using a named numeric vector as below:

```
> trans.vec.num=  c("A"=4.0, "A-"=3.7,
+    "B+" = 3.3, "B" = 3.0,
+    "B-" = 2.7, "C+" = 2.3,
+    "C" = 2.0, "C-" = 1.7,
+    "D+" = 1.3, "D" = 1.0,
+    "F" = 0.0)
> filtered_data$num.num <- trans.vec.num[filtered_data$Grade]
> str(filtered_data)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Grade   : Factor w/ 11 levels "A","A-","B","B-",..: 1 5 6 2 9 3 4 8 7 10 ...
 $ num.char: chr  "4.0" "2.7" "2.3" "3.7" ...
 $ num.num : num  4 2.7 2.3 3.7 1.3 3.3 3 1.7 2 1 ...
```

Notice that the original Grade column was a factor but that did not bother the "["-function.